# Not sure why I am getting "error 'Navbar' is defined but never used" when using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

So I imported my *Navbar* component from *Navbar.vue*, and then tried to include that in my *app.vue* - but I get the error `error  'Navbar' is defined but never used`. I'm not sure why this is happening, but I am a beginner with Vue so its likely my limited understanding.

---

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar/>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue'
</script>
```

---

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, basically I just didn't realise you had to include the following:

---

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Navbar
  }
}
```

---

Hope this can help someone!

Comment: Great that you've figured it out. You can mark your own answer as the accepted answer in 48 hours.